# Add dataframe columns to list based on condition that if it is 1 then it should be in list else not

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in this format :

```
   P00  P1  P10 P11 P12 P13 P14 P15

    0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   
    0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   
    0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   
    0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
```

For each row of my dataframe, I want to retrieve the name of the column where row = 1 on a list .

output:

```
['P10'] 

['P1','P10']

['P10','P11','P12','P13','P14','P15']

['P10','P12']
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You have just to add astype(str) to the solution given by StupidWolf like this :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'P00':[0,0,0,0],'P1':[0,1,0,0],
'P10':[1,1,1,1],'P11':[0,0,1,0]})

dt=df.apply(lambda x:df.columns[x==1].tolist(),axis=1)
dt.astype(str)
```

Output :

```
0           ['P10']
1     ['P1', 'P10']
2    ['P10', 'P11']
3           ['P10']
dtype: object
```